# Remove html tags from string using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to know how to remove html tags from a string using jquery, html looks like this

```
var string = '<p><marquee> some text </marquee>/p>';
```

now i want to remove all html tags and just want the plain text from it.

thank you

Answer (score 5):

[jQuery text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) will help you like this :

```
var willbeequaltosometext = $("marquee").text();
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do this yust like this:

```
$('<p><marquee> some text </marquee></p>').text()
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
alert($('<li>Some text...</li>').text());
```